# Thrown expression type 'Error' does not confirm 'Error'

Tags: swift

I try to develop SwiftyDB SQLite app in Xcode. After pod installation below error showing:

> Thrown expression type 'Error' does not confirm 'Error'

Code:

```
static func verifyResultCode(_ resultCode: Int32, forHandle handle: OpaquePointer) throws {
    guard isSuccess(resultCode) else {
        throw Error(rawValue: resultCode)! // error showing here
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: Show your `Error` enum.